# How to ensure that not all the formulas are satisfied at the same time using Boolector?

Tags: smt

so I'm experimenting with [boolector](https://github.com/Boolector/boolector) and I have reached the point where I have `N` number of `BoolectorNode` representing `N` different formula. I'd like to have a function that ensures that a minimum of `0` and a maximum of `N-1` formula are true at the same time. I imagine that with some loops I can achieve that but I was wondering if using some pre-existing function available in `boolector` I could achieve that easily.

Comment: [One of many publications](https://easychair.org/publications/open/3XKD)

Comment: Such constraints are called "pseudoboolean." See this in the z3 context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20226474/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-encode-pseudoboolean-constraints-in-z3